# Why won't text will not align to center in <section> background?

Tags: css, background, width, html

I am learning HTML and CSS. My `<h3>` text will not align to the center of the page. I know this has to do with the background width being 50%, but I need that in order for the page to be two colors. Any way around this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prociono" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <section id="header">

        <h1 class="name">Jessica Shae</h1>


        <div class="container heading">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/7.jpg" class="display">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/2.jpg" class="display">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/9.jpg" class="display">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-xs-center">
                        <a href="#gallery"<i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 

            </div>
        </div>


    </section>

    <!-- Gallery -->

    <section id="gallery">

        <h2 class="title">The Dark Room</h2>

        <div class="container photo-collection">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/1.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/10.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/4.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/18.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/6.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/8.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/12.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/11.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 affect">
                    <img src="img/14.jpg" class="work">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>




    </section>

    <section class="contact-me">
        <div class="contact">
            <h3>Contact Me</h3>
        </div>


    </section>
```

And my CSS:

```css
* {
     /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
     background: #070606;
}

/* HEADER */

.display {
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 6%;
}

.heading {
max-width: 100%;
}

.name {
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 500%;
      font-weight: 100;
      text-align: center;
      color: whitesmoke;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-top: 15px;
}

h1:after {
      display: block;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: #e62222;  /*Great way to give single line color */
      content: " ";
      width: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
}

.fa {
      margin-top: 18px;
}

.fa:link, /*Prevents color change when clicked */
.fa:visited {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: #bdc3c7;
}

.fa:hover,
.fa:active {
            color: #ebedee;
}


/* GALLERY */


.work {
       width: 300px;
       height: 100%;
       margin-top: 60px;
       margin-bottom: 60px;
       border: 3px solid white;
       }

 .title {
       font-family: 'Prociono', serif;
       font-size: 350%;
       color: whitesmoke;
       text-align: center;
       padding-top:40px;

 }

.affect img {
           opacity: 0.2;
           background-color: #070606;
           transition: opacity .35s, transform .35s;
           transform: scale(1.0);
}

   .affect:hover img {

    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.15);

}

/* CONTACT */

.contact {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, gray 50%);
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Put the text int a different div?

Comment: I have tried, that does not work.

Comment: "I know this has to do with the background width being 50%, but I need that in order for the page to be two colors."  
  
There are a million ways to get a two-color background without doing this. The easiest would probably be a two-color linear-gradient with a hard stop, like so:  
`background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, blue 50%);`  
  
But you could also use a background image or `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements positioned behind the content.

Comment: I didn't know there were a "million ways". Like I said still learning(: anyways, that does not work due to the fact that the contact text is then outside the background color (ontop). @CapitalQ

Comment: Does this CodePen help? http://codepen.io/capitalq/pen/VmwapE

Comment: No unfortunately. There must be something else in my code blocking this. I will have to ask a new question with all my css added.

Comment: @TempleNaylor You don't need to create another question for this, just edit this one.

Comment: Hi guys, I am sorry, having trouble trying to edit code on the question. I did so, but for future reference are there keyboard shortcuts I can use? By the way, I should mention this two color background I am trying to achieve is only for the contact section and not the rest of the webpage. @CapitalQ

Comment: I did so @YuriRamos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule in your CSS is setting the background color of every element to #070606, as you're using the asterisk, which is a wildcard selector that catches everything.

`* { background: #070606; }`

If you only meant to set the background color of the page to that color, use `body` instead of `*`.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as having solved your question? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your text is not centered because text-align:center refers to the parent width so it means it's centered in the 50% wide div. In order to center it you can  wrap contact and h3 in a wrapper with a position relative. Then set position absolute to h3 (you need to move it out of .contact div) and set 100% width for h3. It should work in that way. Remember that if you position if with absolute you need to set up height for parent.

```css
.contact {
        background-color: black;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 50%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        height:100%;
    }

h3 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 300%;
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
 }
.wrapper{
position:relative;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
    <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="contact"></div>
    <h3>Contact me</h3>
    </section>
```

But this example is not a best approach. The best approach in this case is to make a gradient background (like showed in comments snippets) for the parent container with 50/50 of the colors. This won't make your HTML structure and CSS code messy.